# How to catch IVMRunner output?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to implements a particular function to my own eclipse-plugin. I would to run an external main (it is situated into plugin target workspace).
This is the code in which i've implemented my solution:

```
public static void runInstaller (String prjInstaller, String url, String usr, String pwd, boolean jmes, boolean cal, boolean jpm, boolean prc, boolean hmi, boolean others, boolean tst) throws Exception {
    List<IJavaProject> javaProjects = getWsProjects ();
    for (IJavaProject jPrj : javaProjects) {
        if (jPrj.getElementName ().equals (prjInstaller)) {
            try {
                IVMInstall vm = JavaRuntime.getVMInstall (jPrj);
                if (vm == null) { vm = JavaRuntime.getDefaultVMInstall (); }
                IVMRunner vmr = vm.getVMRunner (ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE);
                String[] cp = JavaRuntime.computeDefaultRuntimeClassPath (jPrj);
                VMRunnerConfiguration config = new VMRunnerConfiguration ("net.synergy.setup.Installer", cp);
                String[] args = { url, usr, pwd, String.valueOf (jmes), String.valueOf (cal), String.valueOf (jpm), String.valueOf (hmi), String.valueOf (prc), String.valueOf (others), String.valueOf (tst) };
                config.setProgramArguments (args);
                ILaunch launch = new Launch (null, ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null);
                vmr.run (config, launch, null);
                break;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw e;
            } // try-catch      
        } // if 
    } // for
} // runInstaller
```

This solution works properly. I instantiate a new vm in which run my main class. I'm able also to pass arguments to "runner". It's fantastic.
My problem, now, is how to catch the System out of this process. In this main class i have a few system.out.print, and i would to see catch this output and redirect it to a logfile or, better, console.
The process run properly (it's a process that populate an empty db and i can see the result after i run the thread) but i need to see the console output.

It's a possibile solution, also, to wrap this thread into job manager of Eclipse so i can see the progression of thread.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the `run` will create an `IProcess` for the running code. This will be added to the `ILaunch` (see the `getProcesses` method). The `IProcess` has a stream proxy for the output (see `getStreamsProxies` method)

Comment: Oh.. thanks! It's seems working!